# Runtim Exception extends Exception and Custom Exception extends from Exception Why the later one is compile time exception and other is not?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

In Java I have a Exception class that extends from `Exception`, But whenever I throw it, the compiler says that it needs to be caught/ must declare that methods `throws` Exception.

When I use a `RuntimeException` that extends from `Exception`, the compiler does not stop, It takes them as **Runtime Exception** and we need not handle it.

Is there a way where I can  make a MyException extend from Exception and still have it as runtime exception.? or What makes this as possibility in class `RuntimeException`

```
private void compileTime() throws MyException{
        throw new MyException();
    }

    private void runTime() {
        throw new MyRuntimeException();
    }

    class MyException extends Exception {

    }
    class MyRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {

    }
```

Answer (score 12):

RuntimeException are a subset of unchecked exceptions for exceptions from which recovery is possible.

unchecked exceptions are not checked at compile-time which means that the compiler doesn't require methods to catch or to specify (with a throws) them.

> **The *unchecked* exceptions classes are the class RuntimeException and
>   its subclasses, and the class Error and its subclasses.** All other
>   exception classes are ***checked*** exception classes.

Please check the Exception Hierarchy through this image : 
[image: exception hierarchy]

In short, Any exception that derives from "Exception" is a checked exception, whereas a class that derives from RuntimeException is un-checked. RuntimeExceptions do not need to be explicitly handled by the calling code.

Comment: The question is how it does it internally?

Answer (score 3):

No way. According to specifications, only exceptions extended from `RuntimeException` class or `Error` class are considered as unchecked exceptions (JLS 7, p. 11.1.1).

Comment: +1 All other Throwable subclasses, even direct sub-classes of Throwable are checked. (i.e. it might not be an Exception or an Error)

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling a "compile-time" exception is known as a Checked exception. As you say the compiler will require you to include it in your method signature and your callers will need to handle the possibility that it may be thrown.

RuntimeException is explicitly intended for the "unchecked" exception case.

From the docs

> A method is not required to declare in its throws clause any
>   subclasses of RuntimeException that might be thrown during the
>   execution of the method but not caught.

So just extend RuntimeException if you want an unchecked excption.

Answer (score 0):

**RuntimeException** doesn't need the try-catch combo or throws in the beginning of method. Simply because it happens in runtime such as you want to refer the 14th element of a 10 element long array or get a NullPointerException because you forgot to set value of something, these cases cannot be predicted since the program would work well with the right structures. Also as others say, this is un-checked.

**Exception** is different, you have to tell the program what to do with the well known exception cases. That means the complier will force you to handle the exception somehow before it starts to run.